# Loading data using LOAD FILE command - delimiter

Tags: mysql

I would take data from csv file into my table. I'm using command:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:\\...\\file.csv' INTO TABLE table FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

The problem is that I have data as below:

```
Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4
1,name11,name21,name31
2,"name21, aaa.",name22,name23
```

First row is ok, but second not, because `"name21, aaa."` is reading as two columns so I don't have `name23` in table.

Any idea how can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand **LOAD DATA INFILE** syntax.

Check this link [**MySQL - LOAD DATA INFILE**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html).

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\...\\file.csv' INTO TABLE table
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5...)
```

Comment: It would be great if you explain it.

Comment: You need to use this enclosed BY '"' because you have text which is in "text" format.